# Dynamic query in rails where condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

How can we get a dynamic query in Rails such that we can only search the field that is present in the array with AND operator? Example:

```
car_type = ['tow', 'drive']
Vehicle.where("tow=? AND drive=?", true, true)

car_type = ['tow']
Vehicle.where("tow=?", true)
```

Comment: Use include? check if value is present or not car_type = ['tow', 'drive']
.include? 'two'
=> true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
q = { tow: true, drive: true }

Vehicle.where(q)
```

You can get `q` dinamically doing:

```
q = car_type.product([true]).to_h
```

Comment: It's pretty straight forward. That's silly of me. Thanks